# Centering block of 2 images and keeping images centered when responsive

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Working in a Wordpress post, I want to add two images side-by-side and keep the block of images centered (one is aligned left, the other right). (That on its own I've got.)

When the page size is smaller, I want the images to stack. (That I've got.)

But the images aren't then centered in the page in this responsive mode. First one is left and the other right.

I've played with different image alignments through WP, but I can't get the combination to work.

Here's my html:

```
<div class="ps-image-container">
  <div class="ps-inner-image-container">
    <div class="ps-responsive">
      <img src="https://passports. ... " class="alignleft" />
    </div>
    <div class="ps-responsive">
      <img src="https://passports. ... " class="alignright" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.ps-image-container {
    display: block;
  /*width: 98%;
  margin: 0 auto;*/
}

.ps-inner-image-container {
  /*display: block;*/
  width: 98%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.ps-image-container::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.ps-responsive {
    width: 49.99999%;
    float: left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){
    .ps-responsive {
        width: 100%;

    }
}
```

There is some key concept that I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your goal correctly, you want to do two things with your responsive layout:

1. Switch the image containers (`.ps-responsive`) between 50% and 100% widths so they go from being side-by-side to stacked (they can stay floated left)
2. Switch the text-align property of these containers between left/right and centred so the images inside them will go from the inner edges of these containers to the center.

It looks like you're close but you don't need so much code. See this fiddle for a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/ds2vuqng/26/

Comment: Wow! This is great. I have just a tiny problem left. When the page is larger, I'd like the images to be evenly spaced across the page so the "group" of the two of them is centered. Right now, the align left within their 50%. Also, below 500px, the images stack but stay aligned left and not centered below the text. (I have set all the images to be alignnone in WP) If I try to style the ps-image-container div, it seems to break the responsiveness of the ps-responsive divs.

Comment: @tangobango I'm not sure if I understand what you mean by having them evenly spaced across the page *and* centered at the same time. It's a bit hard to visualise. Do you mean you want multiple images spaced out in a single row, but two of those images squashed together?  Can you set up a fiddle showing how you want it to look at the larger screen size?

Comment: Hi. Here's the look I want for a full size page. Not necessarily evenly spaced, but centered with some space between. https://jsfiddle.net/tangobango/Lm0kbwdc/

Comment: You could always just add some margin to the 'img' elements in my fiddle, would that work for you? This would spread them out a bit when grouped.

Comment: As I play with it, I see I can take out the css for .ps-responsive:first-chil (which I assume needs a "d" on the end) and .ps-responsive.last (which confuses me) and get the same overall result. I don't see how to add margin without knowing the image sizes.

Comment: Ah yeah don't know what's going on with the original fiddle there, not what I intended sorry - looks like it saved halfway through my last edits - I've updated the fiddle link in my main answer to what it should've been. As for margins, try this: https://jsfiddle.net/ds2vuqng/29/ - is that what you're after?

Comment: Got it! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the float's in css by:

```
clear:both;
```

You can also use Bootstrap to fix this and using the container and text-center as a part of you class in ps-inner-image-container like:

```
<div class="row ps-image-container">
  <div class="container text-center ps-inner-image-container">
   <div class="ps-responsive">
     <img src="https://passports. ... " class="alignleft" />
   </div>
   <div class="ps-responsive">
     <img src="https://passports. ... " class="alignright" />
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure if this will fix your problem otherwise write again :-)

Comment: I'm set on the clearing floats. I'm using another theme (Divi) that makes Bootstrap infeasible, as I understand it. Any other ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to add Bootstrap in your header like this:  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: I would avoid using a whole responsive framework like Bootstrap just to fix a small problem, otherwise you're likely to create more problems. Better to just approach this simply and use less code. Also a `.container` element inside a `.row` element is not following correct Bootstrap heirarchy. It should always go `.container > .row > .col...`.